# Blazor conditional if statement for onclick

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a span which should have an onclick attribute if the IsActive bool is true.
Otherwise the span should have no onclick attribute.

e.g.

```
@if (IsActive == true)
{
    <span @onclick="@(e => Go.DoSomething("please"))">
        @s.DisplayText
    </span>
}
else
{
    <span>
        @s.DisplayText
     </span>
}
```

Is there not a way to avoid the repeated code using a ternary operator? e.g.

```
@(IsActive == true ? "add onclick method somehow?" : "")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
<span @onclick="@(e => { if (IsActive) Go.DoSomething("please");})">
    @s
</span>
```

A [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#lambda-expressions) is what I think you are really looking for.

Comment: This is not the same, specially if it is Blazor server, in the question example, requests don't hit the server. in your example they would, it would have an impact on performance.

Comment: @koolaang Can you clarify what you mean by 'not the  same'?

Comment: I found this answer useful for dealing with Click events and Nullable reference types warning. Starting in .NET 6, they're enabled by default for new projects.

Answer (score 10):

A better way to add the condition `IsActive == true` is in the `Go.DoSomething` method. But ideally I would have used a button if its clickable because we can add a `disabled` attribute to a button, in your case you can add the condition inside the `onclick` method.

Just a tip for the button, you can just add your c# boolean property within that attribute like this:

```
<button disabled="@IsActive">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thanks - ended up converting to a button and using the disabled attribute

Comment: Updated the answer to add a small tip as you are using a button

Comment: From the context I think it should be `disabled="@(!IsActive)"` .

Answer (score 4):

Other answers are kind of wrong. There is a difference between registering an event method as a lambda and not registering an event if not necessary.

If you move the condition to a lambda function, anytime someone click your method will run. It would have a performance impact on your app, especially if it is Blazor Server since the round trip has to happen and the logic happens on your server.

```
@ondclick=@(Active?() => Go.DoSomething:null)
```

will not register the event if it is not active so no load on your server.

from [Blazor Repository Tests](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/test/testassets/BasicTestApp/CounterComponent.razor#L3)

Comment: According to the documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-server), UI events are sent from the browser to the server.

I would assume that would be ALL Blazor events given that the browser is connected to the backend server via a SignalR connection.

Comment: but if there is no UI even, there is no traffic to the server. that is my whole point. using this approach you don't register the UI event.

Comment: @koolaang How slow/fast is this server-client feedback loop. I am just starting with Blazor and haven't pushed any production code yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add something for people having a similar problem:

If you have more HTML code than a single span and you would need it twice because of an if-else-statement, I would create a own Blazor component (e.g. MyComponent.razor) and use component parameters.
This way you don´t have much duplicate code in an if-else-statement.

Comment: Good option also

Comment: I was hoping someone would answer this and avoid all the unnecessary binds.

Comment: Question: So after adding a component we still use if/else inside that? Wouldnt that be the same thing?

Comment: Not necessarily the same, you could for example create a component parameter named color and call it in the if statement with color=blue and in the else statement with color=green. You also need the if-else-statement, that's true. This solution is not like a ternary operator, but it might save you some lines of code regarding the size of your component.

Comment: It's true that there will be less code in the main page, but its still the same thing " if " the new component is not shared anywhere else in the project.

Comment: No I don't think so. If you for example have 5 divs inside one div, and the background should be blue for one case and green for the other: Then you would have 5 divs in the if-statement and 5 divs in the else. If you refactor them to a component with one parameter @backgroundcolor, then you would save to write 5 divs in the main page but there would also just be 5 divs in the component, not 10.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying, as you gave example of sharing the component which in that case will be less code and it is the best way of doing, if you don't have to share that code then a new component is essentially the same thing as doing it within the page.